# How to edit swap partitions?

Tags: partitioning, swap, disk-management

I've done several installations of different Ubuntu versions on my machine one over the other from a CD or live usb, and now I have a mess of swap partitions (something like 10 of them), so I need to eliminate all those and create a new one.
I also need to know how to tell the system that the new partition is the one for swap -- otherwise the system won't recognize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Gparted to edit partitions.  Delete the unwanted swap partitions and add a new one.  Try to avoid moving existing partitions, as this operation takes a long time, although in-place resizing is usually pretty fast.  Basically, if the tan part moves, it'll take a while.  And back up everything important first.

Swap partitions tend to be recognized automatically, but you can edit /etc/fstab to tell it to use that as a swap.  First right-click on the swap partition and select "information", and copy or write down the UUID.  Next edit /etc/fstab:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Remove any lines whose third field is "swap" (be conservative; if you're not sure what to do, leave a line alone) and add a new line like this:

```
UUID=uuid     none     swap    0     0
```

Replace those spaces with tabs, and replace the lowercase string "uuid" with the UUID you copied or wrote down earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, clone ur system in a USB or Portable HD and then, format the device. It works much better! :P To clone ubuntu u can install Garfio or Ddrescue! see more [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/8225-clone-your-ubuntu-installation-onto-a-new-hard-disk)